# Are you still supposed to use controllers when using Razor Pages?

Tags: controller, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

I'm confused on wheter you should still use controllers in your Core 2.0 project if you are using razorpages, since they removed the pre-made controllers folder from Core 1.0.
Asking as im using Razorpages, Entity framework and sql.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is up to you. There are people who still use controllers in ASP.NET Core 2 because they do not like the idea of Razor Pages. You can have both of them in the same project. I personally like Razor pages but I still use Controllers when I have to make an ajax call in order to get data from server to update the contents of the page. For ajax calls I also use the razor page by defining handlers to get the data.

Controllers also can be used in a Razor Page project in order to create web services so that other application to be able to retrieve information from the Razor Page application.

Comment: So it is completely fine to use both? Funny thing is im asking because i need to make ajax calls to save data to the server. Thank you for yet another answer to my questions haha!

Comment: Yes it is fine to use both. You can even have razor pages and controllers with view in the same project.